# Conditional directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

Depending of one directive logic I want conditionally add another directive to the SAME element.

For example:

- I use 3rd party angular.bootstrap.tooltip directive
- add tooltip ONLY IF some condition is met
- do not initialise tooltip directive if it's not necessary

I want to dynamically add tooltip (or any other directive) ONLY IF condition is met.

1. [Here is a first attempt](http://plnkr.co/edit/x5DpP8G6imJ3yeXbdZhW?p=preview)
2. [and second with $compile/priority/terminal](http://plnkr.co/edit/i08WNBxiuINV7vAMgoEd?p=preview)

Is there a better way than using $compile?

[Here is original Angular group discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/hRApmZhe3bg)

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the first one. It looks a lot simpler than the second one. Unless there is a good reason to do so. The first directive is easy to understand for me as an outsider while the second one takes more time to get my head around.

Only if you run into trouble later on, you could reconsider your solution. But why worry now when there is no reason for it (yet)?

Comment: yes, it's simpler. but it creates tooltip for every item. what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I think `terminal` option is ideal and will solve your problems. If set to `true` then the current priority will be the last set of directives which will execute on an element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/aNCY3/

Comment: not exactly what I'm looking for. there should be conditional directive. you made noEntry directive priority above ng-repeat so it's executed once but not appended since ng-repeat uses transclusion. see http://jsfiddle.net/rRUr8/2/